# Java: methods using array variables

Tags: java

So I made this code using various snippets on the web so that I could see how it all works, But For some strange reason the 4th "For" loop is skipped entirely, And I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. It is a command line using code.

```
public class New1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of clicks before repeat: ");
        int Clicks = in.nextInt();
        int rep2 = 0;
        int Waits[] = new int[Clicks];
        Clicks = Clicks * 2;
        int Coords[] = new int[Clicks];
        Clicks = Clicks / 2;

        int Gung;
        int Ho;
        int Yo;

        int xco = 0;
        int yco = 1;

        if(Clicks > 0)
        {
            for (int rep = 0; rep < Coords.length; rep++)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter x coord: ");
                Coords[rep] = in.nextInt();
                rep++;
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print("Enter y coord: ");
                Coords[rep] = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print("Enter the pause (In seconds) between this click and the next click: ");
                Waits[rep2] = in.nextInt();
                rep2++;
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            rep2 = 0;
            for (int rep3 = 0; rep3 < Waits.length; rep3++)
            {
                Waits[rep3] = Waits[rep3] * 1000;
            }
            System.out.print("How many times to repeat click sequence? : ");
            int Revolutions = in.nextInt();

            for (int counter = 0; counter > Revolutions; counter++)
            {
                for (int Flicks = 0; Flicks > Clicks; Flicks++)
                {
                    Gung = Coords[xco];
                    Ho = Coords[yco];
                    Yo = Waits[Flicks];
                    Click(Gung, Ho);
                    Thread.sleep(Yo);
                    xco += 2;
                    yco += 2;
                }
                xco = 0;
                yco = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Click(int x, int y)
    {
        Robot bot = null;
        try 
        {
            bot = new Robot();
        } 
        catch (Exception failed) 
        {
            System.err.println("Failed instantiating Robot: " + failed);
        }
        int mask = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
        bot.mouseMove(x, y);
        bot.mousePress(mask);
        bot.mouseRelease(mask);
    }

    public static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int ar = 0; ar < n; ar++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[ar] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Edit: The 4th "For" loop is

```
                    for (int Flicks = 0; Flicks > Clicks; Flicks++)
                    {
                        Gung = Coords[xco];
                        Ho = Coords[yco];
                        Yo = Waits[Flicks];
                        Click(Gung, Ho);
                        Thread.sleep(Yo);
                        xco += 2;
                        yco += 2;
                    }
```

Comment: I am assuming the 4th loop is in the method printArray().  Is that correct?

Comment: The 4th for loop is in a method...which is never called. Maybe you should start with some tutorials? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: The 4th for loop is actually the one that uses the Click() Method, I only used printArray() to check out the arrays to see if they were working properly

Comment: There are at least two loops in your code which use '>' condition instead of '<'.

Comment: Well, That was the problem, Thank you very much Oleg Estekhin. Now to figure out GUI's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//first way
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
//second way
for(int i : arr) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");
}
//third way
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

There three basic ways to print all elements in array. Advice: you should avoid using static methods, it is wrong in your case.

```
New1 task = new New1();
task.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

The fourth for loop is:

```
public static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int ar = 0; ar < n; ar++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[ar] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

As you can see it is inside a method called printArray().  There is nothing wrong with the array.  It is just fine.  The problem is that the method is never called thus the for loop never runs.

Here is a [java methods tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm).